# List ordering in Python. Very simple

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
input= ['canter creant cretan nectar',
        'opt top pot',
        'preprosessing' ,
        'subessential suitableness']
```

I want the output to be

```
output= ['subessential suitableness',
         'canter creant cretan nectar',
         'opt top pot']
```

Thus, I want reorder the input by the length of the words. Since "subessential" is the longest words, it should be placed at first and etc. Meawhile, I need to eliminate 'preprosessing' since it is a singleton

I tried to use .join() and split. I am new to python and it took me a while to search and try, but it's still not working. I hope you can help!

Comment: Did you try using `sort` or `sorted`?

Comment: Length of the *first* word, or total length of words?

Comment: Length of the first word, however, if there only one word in an entry. The word should be eliminated. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @user3320487: define 'eliminated'; removed from the output altogether? That's a separate step entirely, you can easily filter out phrases from a list where there is no whitespace.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, it should be removed from the output. Thanks for you help and I am sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorted alone won't work since I want order by the length of the first word, not the total length of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `sorted()` a `key` function to determine the sort 'value' for each entry:

```
output = sorted(input, key=lambda l: len(l.split(None, 1)[0]), reverse=True)
```

would sort on the length of the first word in each phrase; `reverse=True` makes sure the longest word is sorted first.

`.split(None, 1)` limits the splitting to just the first word; no need to split the rest of the line too.

Demo:

```
>>> input = ['canter creant cretan nectar', 'opt top pot', 
...          'subessential suitableness']
>>> sorted(input, key=lambda l: len(l.split(None, 1)[0]), reverse=True)
['subessential suitableness', 'canter creant cretan nectar', 'opt top pot']
```

Removing single words from your input list is a separate problem; filter your list in a generator expression or list comprehension:

```
no_singletons = [p for p in with_singletons if ' ' in p]
```

Combining the two would be:

```
>>> input = ['canter creant cretan nectar', 'opt top pot', 'preprosessing', 
...          'subessential suitableness']
>>> sorted((p for p in input if ' ' in p), key=lambda l: len(l.split()[0]),
...        reverse=True)
['subessential suitableness', 'canter creant cretan nectar', 'opt top pot']
```

where the generator expression pre-filters the input list.

Comment: Do you authorize me to edit your post in order to format the code parts in a more readable way ?

Comment: @eyquem: Rather not; the samples are Python sessions, I can wrap those a little, but I am happy enough with the style.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That really helps! I really want to get familiar with python. I used Java and C mostly. Where is your goto place to see what are the tools available? How will you go about to practice and use them! Thanks again! You are really an expert! @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user3320487: But the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/) is excellent and well worth browsing through.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks again! I have to wait for a while until I can accept an answer and you are moving so fast in solving problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and faster solution:

```
sorted( (x for x in input if ' 'in x),
        key = lambda x: -x.find(' '))
# time: 100


sorted( (x for x in input if ' 'in x),
        key = lambda x: x.find(' '),reverse=True)
# time: 107


sorted((p for p in input if ' ' in p),
       key=lambda l: len(l.split()[0]),
       reverse=True)
# time: 133
```